# Multiple string matches with indexOf()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im pretty sure my syntax this wrong because the script only works if the string matches "Video", if the string has the "word "Audio" it is ignored. Also since the href tags have a value of "#" the redirect for "../../../index.html" doesnt work.

js

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isIE8 = /MSIE 8.0/i.test(ua);
if (isIE8) {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var srcTag = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        if (srcTag.indexOf('Video' || 'Audio') > -1) {
            if (confirm('Download Safari? \n\n http://apple.com/safari/download/')) {
            window.location = 'http://apple.com/safari/download/';
            } else { window.location = '../../../index.html';}
        } else {
            alert('no match');
        }
    });
}
```

html

```
<a href="#"><img src="Video/000_Movies/assets/005_CCC_Jesus_Story_80x60.jpg" />test1</a> 
<a href="#"><img src="Audio/000_Movies/assets/006_GSP_Gods_Story_80x60.jpg" />test2</a> 
<a href="#"><img src="Media/000_Movies/assets/002_God_Man_80x60.jpg" />test3</a>
```

Comment: srcTag.indexOf('Video') > -1 || srcTag.indexOf('Audio') > -1

Comment: try using an absolute url for this part:
window.location = '../../../index.html'

Comment: it needs to be a relative url because it will be running locally and there is no way of knowing what the users drive letter will be.

Comment: you can build it from the window.location.href object

Comment: Here is a reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's far shorter to turn this into a regular expression.

```
if ( srcTag.match( /(video|audio)/ ) ) {
  /* Found */
} else {
  /* Not Found */
}
```

On a side note, please don't do what you're attempting to do. Asking users to download Safari when they're using Internet Explorer 8 is doing a disservice to the Internet, as well as to that user.

As for redirecting the domain to another location, you should use `.preventDefault()` to keep the browser from following the link:

```
$("a.videoDownload").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if ( this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src.match( /(video|audo)/ ) ) {
    window.location = confirm( 'Download Safari?' )
      ? "http://apple.com/safari/download" 
      : "../../../index.html" ;
  } else {
    /* No match */
  }
});
```

Again, please don't *actually* do this. Nobody wants to be *that guy*, and when you tell users to download another browser, you're being *that guy*.

Comment: /(video|audio)/.test( srcTag ) look better to me.

Comment: isnt str.indexOf( 'string' ) faster than regex?

Comment: @qodeninja The danger with `.indexOf` is that it could return `0`, if your match happens at the beginning of the string. `0` is falsy, and as such will be treated as no match found. That being said, you can use `~` to avoid that: `~"foo".indexOf("f");` results in `-1`, which is truthy.

Comment: @JonathanSampson that would negate the usefulness of .indexOf(), falsy values should be strict type checked anyway via '==='. Are you suggesting not using indexOf()? In the benchmark examples Ive seen indexOf perform 12x faster than regEx ( http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-indexof )

Comment: @qodeninja What would negate the usefulness of `.indexOf`? The `~` bitwise operator? If so, that's simply not true. If your goal is to know whether the substring is present or not, `~` is sufficient to protect you from falsy return values. There is no equality checked in the conditions, so `===` is irrelevant - we're not looking for a specific index, we're looking for any index. Don't micro-optimize unless it's necessary.

Comment: +1 for your sidenote! Also, I love that you integrated purely simply regex for a solution.

Answer (score 9):

`'Video' || 'Audio'` is a logical OR. A non-empty string is implicitly a true value in JavaScript, and thus the short-circuited OR is not evaluated and this collapses to just `'Video'`. This is why you see the results you do.

Others have pointed you in correct directions to resolve.

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining where his error is and **why** it is causing the error

Answer (score 4):

I think you probably want the OR (||) operator outside indexOf as so:

```
if ((srcTag.indexOf('Video') !== -1) || (srcTag.indexOf('Audio') !== -1)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is 2 separate indexOf like below,

```
srcTag.indexOf('Video') != -1  || srcTag.indexOf('Audio') != -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you would need to something like this do this:

```
if (srcTag.indexOf('Video') > -1 || srcTag.indexOf('Audio') > -1) {
```

Comment: @qodeninja: only with a single string, but against multiple `indexOf()` searches, such as above, `test()` (regex) becomes [more efficient](https://jsperf.com/zotero/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simple recursion function you can get the index of for a multiple  matches

```
function getMultipleIndexOf(str, searchQuery, acc = 0, result = []) {
  if (!str || !searchQuery) {
    return { result, acc };
  }
  const foundIndex = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLowerCase());
  if (foundIndex < 0) {
    return { result, acc };
  }
  return getMultipleIndexOf(
    str.slice(foundIndex + searchQuery.length),
    searchQuery,
    acc + foundIndex + searchQuery.length,
    [...result, acc + foundIndex]
  );
}

const res = getMultipleIndexOf('long text some how long text!!', 'te');
// { result: [ 5, 24 ], acc: 26 }
```

just ignore the acc it is required to keep track of the previously found text

Answer (score -1):

Its quite faster with regex and ever better with [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/).

```js
var sourceString = 'hello world, i am web developer';
if (XRegExp.test(sourceString, /(hello|web)/)) {
  // yes, `hello` or  `web` is found in `sourceString`
}
```

Execution Time is 0.10595703125ms

Answer (score -2):

This will also work:

```
if (srcTag.indexOf('Video') >= -1 || srcTag.indexOf('Audio') >=-1 ) {
```

Comment: it will always be greater than or equal to -1 right?

Answer (score -3):

This Worked for me:

```
if (srcTag.indexOf('Video' | 'Audio' ) >= -1 ) {
```

Comment: This literally always returns true, no matter what https://jsfiddle.net/6rnaoa0u/

Comment: You should probably read up on what a [bitwise operator is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)