# Search word positions in a string

Tags: javascript

i don't know how I can know the positions of multiple words in a string with match, for example I have the string `"So, Ryan likes the movie Saving Private Ryan, true?"` the word match is Ryan, so the output is 4,40

Comment: maybe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537294/multiple-string-matches-with-indexof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), like:

```
function getWordPositions(str, match){
  var index = str.indexOf(match), result = [];

  while (index > -1){
    result.push(index);

    index = str.indexOf(match, index + match.length);               
  }

  return result;
}
```

> The [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.
>
> ```
> str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
> ```