# Check if element contains one of three string in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When DOM ready, I would like to check if an element on the page contains one of three strings. Currently, I am doing it like this, but this is not working as expected because indexOf is usually used in combination with arrays:

```
jQuery('li.woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method.method')[0].innerHTML.indexOf('iDEAL' || 'Sofortbanking' || 'Bancontact / MisterCash') > 1
```

How can I rewrite this in the most effective way to check if the element contains one of the three strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of needles, and then `Array.some` to check if the element contains any of them

```
let needles  = ['iDEAL', 'Sofortbanking', 'Bancontact', 'Bancontact / MisterCash'];
let haystack = $('li.woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method.method').html();
let result   = needles.some( needle => haystack.includes( needle ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = ...
var match = new Array('iDEAL' , 'Sofortbanking' , 'Bancontact / MisterCash');
var found = false;
for(var i=0;i<3;++i){
    if(html.indexOf(match[i])!=-1){
        found = true;
    }
}
//use `found`
```

Comment: here you are declaring open variables though

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try on it.

```js
var html, salient;

html = $("li.woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method.method").html();
salient = [ "iDEAL", "Sofortbanking", "Bancontact / MisterCash" ];

for (i = 0; i < salient.length; i++)
{
  if (html.indexOf(salient[i]) !== -1)
  {
    // it contains string i
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to use a RegEx, which is not necessarily better:

```js
var html;

html = $("li.woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method.method").html();

if (html.match(/(?:iDEAL|Sofortbanking|Bancontact.*MisterCash)/))
{
  // it contains one of those strings
}
```

Comment: ha, same solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Stein which is present, Use `match` function.

If you just want to check whether it is there or not, then use the `test` in JavaScript

```
/(iDEAL|Sofortbanking|Bancontact|MisterCash){1,}/.test(
      jQuery('li.woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method.method')[0].innerHTML);
```

The regular expression

```
/(iDEAL|Sofortbanking|Bancontact|MisterCash){1,}/
```

Will match 1 or more occurances of that words

Answer (score -1):

The || (Or operator) does not work that way, 
I would suggest using the || outside of indexOf()
Like so

`indexOf('iDEAL')  > 1 || indexOf('Sofortbanking') > 1 || indexOf('...')>1`
[Have a Look at a similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537294/multiple-string-matches-with-indexof)

Comment: can you please improve your answer and use the tools to highlight the code?