# OR in jQuery check on url

Tags: jquery

Im trying to add this line of code on my website to check for a word in my url and then hide an element. But its only work for one word. I want to check for X words with OR.

Im trying this code but doesnt work correctly. Any suggestion?

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('term1','term2') < 0 ) {
        document.getElementById("element").style.display="none";
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) takes searchValue and fromIndex. How does `term2` become index? Also Do you have an element with id as `element`?

Comment: You need to use `||`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple string matches with indexOf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537294/multiple-string-matches-with-indexof)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

const s=window.location.href;

if (s.indexOf('term1') < 0 || s.indexOf('term2') < 0 ) {
        document.getElementById("element").style.display="none";
}
});
```

Comment: with 

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

??

Comment: @nonliner Yes,  I just posted the part that should be changed. Another code remains the same

Comment: No it's not working. Thank you anyway

Comment: @nonliner Can you post window.location.href string pls?  and what is not working?

Comment: Everything works fine! I had a typo. Thank you again for your help!!